# Using bool/flags to govern C++ program flow

Tags: c++

I find myself consistently creating flags within my C++ program, that are later checked to determine if I need to do something, and it honestly feels kind of "hack-y" despite being a simple solution.

For example, Let's say I have a function:

```
update_employee_salary(EmployeeList employees_to_update )
```

`update_employee_salary`:

1. Connects to the database
2. Iterates through all employees in the EmployeeList and gets their status (salaried, or hourly) and creates two separate employee list (hourly_emp, salary_emp)
3. Updates my employee_data in cache
4. Writes that employee data to the database

If the employee is an executive, I want to generate notices/logs that Executive salaries were updated.

I also want to ensure that if for some reason, after reading from the database, I am unable to write to the database, that I back everything out. For this reason, I don't want to generate the notice until I guarantee it's been written to the database, so I'll create a bool elist_contains_execs flag that is checked after the database has been updated to generate the notice.

I find myself doing things like this for all sorts of situations, and it feels gross every time I do it, but often it seems better than iterating through the list a second time to determine if it contains executives after the database update.

Question: Is using flags in C++ feel hacky to anyone else? Or do we just accept that it's often a simple solution. What are the cons of using flags. For example, can it make code more difficult to maintain.

Comment: If you use that flags inside your local scope i think it's okay (and i think Ixrec is right with his answer!)....  its hard to answer you question in general, in some cases you could use more object based approaches to avoid you so called "flags". In your concrete example you could think about sql transactions.....

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like these "flags" of yours are what we would call "global variables", variables declared at the highest possible scope so that they can be read from and written to from anywhere in your program.

The problem with globals is, of course, that they can be read from and written to from *anywhere*, which effectively means any piece of code that touches a global is impossible to (fully) understand without searching for every other piece of code touching the same global. This is indeed a classic maintenance headache. Globals should always be an option of last resort, used only when you're sure that every alternative would somehow be even worse.

For the specific example you gave, the first alternative that comes to my mind is a simple output parameter:

```
bool execUpdated = false;
int rcode = update_employee_salary(employees_to_update, &execUpdated);
if(rcode != 0) {
  // handle the error
} else {
  // handle the success
  if(execUpdated) {
     // show your notification
  }
}
```

Now anyone who sees `update_employee_salary` will instantly be aware of this special check for executive updates, and it's impossible to "break" this function "from the outside" by having other code that fiddles with the wrong globals at the wrong time.

Comment: The flags I'm referring to are not global. They are usually local to a function, where the function does processing first and then execution later. I rarely use global variables.